# sqlite add x days to date (x stored in table)

Tags: c#, sqlite, date, addition, days

I need to do something like this in sqlite (c# app):

```
select DATE(XDATE,'+XDAYS day') from TABLE
```

XDATE and XDAYS fields are strings type, stored in "TABLE" table.

someone understood me and could help me? Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the SqlLite DateTime modifiers (https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html)

> date(timestring, modifier, modifier, ...)
>
> The time string can be followed by zero or more modifiers that alter date and/or time. Each modifier is a transformation that is applied to the time value to its left. Modifiers are applied from left to right; order is important. The available modifiers are as follows.
>
> NNN days
>
> NNN hours
>
> NNN minutes
>
> NNN.NNNN seconds
>
> NNN months
>
> NNN years
>
> start of month start of year start of day weekday N unixepoch
>
> localtime utc

for instance:
SELECT date('now','start of month','+1 month','-1 day');

```
CREATE TABLE [theDates] (
  [d] VARCHAR(100)  NULL,
  [diff] varchar(100)  NULL
)


insert into [TheDates] VALUES ('now', '-10 day')   

Select d, diff, date([d], [diff]) from [TheDates]


d             diff        date([d], [diff])
-------------------------------------------
now           -10 day     2015-06-02
```

if you have numeric data

```
insert into [TheDates] VALUES ('now', -10)   

Select d, diff, date([d], ([diff] || ' day')) from [TheDates]


d             diff        date([d], ([diff] || ' day'))
-------------------------------------------------------
now           -10 day     2015-06-02
```

Comment: I know that. in fact it is what I did in the example. but the difficulty I have is that the number of days I have to add is not a fixed number, is a variable number that is on the table.

Comment: @martin.softpro hope the example explains

Comment: date([d], ([diff] || ' day'))
That is what i was looking for. Thanks !